# Can we move extra properties in the gradle.build file to a separate module?

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, kotlin

I want to know if it's possible to extract ext block in the **build.gradle** file and put it in a separate module within the project so it shareable within all the build-scripts of my project using either **Groovy DSLs** or **Kotlin DSLs**.

```
ext {
    appBoyVersion = '2.0.0'
    supportLibVersion = '27.1.1'
    playServiceLibVersion = '12.0.1'
    crashlyticsVersion = '2.9.1'
    butterknifeVersion = '8.4.0'
    //....

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. 
For example:

```
if (file('../common.gradle').exists()) {
    apply from: '../common.gradle'
} else {
    //use default values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use gradle.properties to define the different versions you are using for your libraries, Like

SUPPORT_PACKAGE_VERSION=27.0.2

GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION=11.8.0

And then use these in respective build.gradle files of all modules

implementation "com.android.support:design:${SUPPORT_PACKAGE_VERSION}"